# Can I play PS Plus free downloaded games after trial period ends?

Tags: ps4

I recently bought a PS4 and got 14 days trial activated on it. So, as PS Plus members get free monthly games, I downloaded Mad Max and Trackmania Turbo, so does it mean I will be unable to play both these game after my trial period ends? Is there any workaround for it if I am unable to play after the trial period ends?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot, In order to play any games that you have added to your account via Playstation Plus, you need an active PS Plus subscription or they will be locked.